# MySQL: Remove JOIN for Matched Row if 2nd Round of Criteria Not Met

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, match

**CONDENSED VERSION**

I'm trying to join a new list with my existing database with no unique identifier -- but I'm trying to figure out a way to do it in one query that's more specific than matching by first name/last name but less specific than by all the fields available (first name/middle name/last name/address/phone).

So my idea was to match solely on first/last name and then try to assign each possible matching field with points to see if anyone who matched had 'zero points' and thus have the first name/last name match stripped from them. Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT *, 
@MidMatch := IF(LEFT(l.middle,1)=LEFT(d.middle,1),"TRUE","FALSE") MidMatch, 
@AddressMatch := IF(left(l.address,5)=left(d.address,5),"TRUE","FALSE") AddressMatch, 
@PhoneMatch := IF(right(l.phone,4)=right(d.phone,4),"TRUE","FALSE") PhoneMatch,  
@Points := IF(@MidMatch = "TRUE",4,0) + IF(@AddressMatch = "TRUE",3,0) + IF(@PhoneMatch = "TRUE",1,0) Points
    FROM list l
    LEFT JOIN database d on IF(@Points <> 0,(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last),(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last AND l.address = d.vaddress));
```

The query runs fine but it does still match people who's first/last names are identical even if their points are zero (and if their addresses don't match).

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for with this roundabout points system? I've found that it helps me a lot when trying to identify which duplicate to choose, so I'm trying to expand it to the initial match. Or should I do something different?

---

**SPECIFIC VERSION**

This is kind of a roundabout idea -- so if somebody has something more straight forward, I'd definitely be willing to bail on this completely and try something else. But basically I have a 93k person table (from a database) that I'm matching against a 92k person table (from a new list). I expect many of them to be the same but certainly not all -- and I'm trying to avoid creating duplicates. Unfortunately, there's no unique identifiers that can be matched, so I'm generally stuck with matching based on some variation of first name, middle name, last name, address, and/or phone number.

The schema for the two tables (list and database) are pretty identical with the fields you see above (first name, middle name, last name, address, phone) -- the only difference is that the database table also has an unique numerical ID that I would use to upload back into the database after this match. Unfortunately the list table has no such ID. Records with the ID would get matched and loaded in on top of the old record and any record without that ID would get loaded as a new record.

What I'm trying to avoid with this question is creating a bunch of different tables and queries that start with a really specific `JOIN` statement and then eventually get down to just first and last name -- since there's likely some folks who should match but have moved and/or gotten a new phone number since this last list.

I could write a very simple query as a `JOIN` and do it numerous times, each time taking out another qualifier:

```
SELECT * 
FROM list l
JOIN database d
ON d.first = l.first AND d.last = l.last AND d.middle = l.middle AND d.address = l.address AND d.phone = l.phone;
```

And I'd certainly feel confident that those people from the new list matched with the existing people in my database, but it'd only return a very small amount of people, then I'd have to go back and loosen the criteria (e.g. drop the middle name restriction, etc.) and continually create tables then merge them all back together at the end along with all the ones that didn't match at all, which I would assume would be the new people.

But is there a way to write the query solely using a first/last name match, then evaluating the other criteria and wiping the match from people who have zero 'points' (below)? Here's what I attempted to do assigning [arbitrary] points to each match:

```
SELECT *, 
@MidMatch := IF(LEFT(l.middle,1)=LEFT(d.middle,1),"TRUE","FALSE") MidMatch, 
@AddressMatch := IF(left(l.address,5)=left(d.address,5),"TRUE","FALSE") AddressMatch, 
@PhoneMatch := IF(right(l.phone,4)=right(d.phone,4),"TRUE","FALSE") PhoneMatch,  
@Points := IF(@MidMatch = "TRUE",4,0) + IF(@AddressMatch = "TRUE",3,0) + IF(@PhoneMatch = "TRUE",1,0) Points
    FROM list l
    LEFT JOIN database d on IF(@Points <> 0,(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last),(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last AND l.address = d.vaddress));
```

The `LEFT` and `RIGHT` formulas within the `IF` statements are just attempting to control for unstandardized data that gets sent. I also  would've done something with a `WHERE` statement, but I still need the `NULL` values to return so I know who matched and who didn't. So I ended up attempting to use an `IF` statement in the `LEFT JOIN` to say that if the `Points` cell was equal to zero, that the `JOIN` statement would get really specific and what I thought would hopefully still return the row but it wouldn't be matched to the database even if their first and last name did.

The query doesn't produce any errors, though unfortunately I'm still getting people back who have zeros in their `Points` column but matched with the database because their first and last names matched (which is what I was hoping the IF/Points stuff would stop).

Is this potentially a way to avoid bad matches, or am I going down the wrong path? If this isn't the right way to go, is there any other way to write one query that will return a full `LEFT JOIN` along with `NULL`s that don't match but have it be more specific than just first/last name but less work than doing a million queries based on a new table each time?

Thanks and hopefully that made some sense!

Comment: Thanks for being specific. But actually I did not read the question - there is so much text. I guess many won't read it. Could you make it straight to the point in way less text?

Comment: @juergend      Ha, yes -- understandable! I'm just always nervous about not being specific enough on here. I added an edit that includes a condensed version that gets to the basic point, I think. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query:

```
SELECT *, 
       @MidMatch := IF(LEFT(l.middle,1)=LEFT(d.middle,1),"TRUE","FALSE") MidMatch, 
       @AddressMatch := IF(left(l.address,5)=left(d.address,5),"TRUE","FALSE") AddressMatch, 
       @PhoneMatch := IF(right(l.phone,4)=right(d.phone,4),"TRUE","FALSE") PhoneMatch,  
       @Points := IF(@MidMatch = "TRUE",4,0) + IF(@AddressMatch = "TRUE",3,0) + IF(@PhoneMatch = "TRUE",1,0) Points
    FROM list l LEFT JOIN
         database d
         on IF(@Points <> 0,(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last),(l.first = d.first AND l.last = d.last AND l.address = d.vaddress));
```

This is making a *serious* mistake with regards to variables.  The simplest is the `SELECT` -- the `SELECT` does not guarantee the order of calculation of expressions, so they could calculated in any order.  And the logic is wrong if `@Points` is calculated first.  This problem is compounded by referring to variables in different clauses.  The SQL statement is a *logical* statement describing the results set, not a programmatic statement of how the query is run.

Let me assume that you have a unique identifier for each row in the database (just to identify the row).  Then you can get the match by using a correlated subquery:

```
select l.*,
       (select d.databaseid
        from database d
        where l.first = d.first and l.last = d.last
        order by (4 * (LEFT(l.middle, 1) = LEFT(d.middle, 1) ) +
                  3 * (left(l.address, 5) = left(d.address, 5)) +
                  1 * (right(l.phone, 4) = right(d.phone, 4))
                 )
        limit 1
       ) as did
from list l;
```

You can join back to the database table to get more information if you need it.

EDIT:

Your comment made it clear.  You don't just want the first and last name but something else as well.

```
select l.*,
       (select d.databaseid
        from database d
        where l.first = d.first and l.last = d.last and
              (LEFT(l.middle, 1) = LEFT(d.middle, 1) or
               left(l.address, 5) = left(d.address, 5) or
               right(l.phone, 4) = right(d.phone, 4)
              )                     
        order by (4 * (LEFT(l.middle, 1) = LEFT(d.middle, 1) ) +
                  3 * (left(l.address, 5) = left(d.address, 5)) +
                  1 * (right(l.phone, 4) = right(d.phone, 4))
                 )
        limit 1
       ) as did
from list l;
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely makes me feel more comfortable than using something like `@Points` -- but while you're query above is much better than mine, won't it still result in a match for people whose first and last name still match even if nothing else does? I was attempting to write something where the first/last name match was the base but that if the literally all the other data conflicted with each other, then it wouldn't attach the `d.databaseid` to that record. A little backwards, but that's the only way I could think to do it.

Comment: @Ryan . . . Try the query. It will return some row if the first and last name matches, even if that is the only row.

Comment: I tried it -- and it does work way better than mine, I know it seems counter intuitive to the join statement -- but I just don't want people to be matched solely if their first and last name matches. If that matches *and* something else, then I'll want that `d.databaseid` to come over. That's what I was attempting to do with the points stuff without having to write a bunch of separate queries.

Comment: @Ryan . . . The `order by` should be doing what you want by selecting the best matching row.

Comment: Yup! That part works great -- but let me know if this makes sense: In your query, it still produces a databaseid if solely the first and last name match -- but I don't trust it if it's just first and last time, I think I'd rather create a new record in the database if nothing matches besides the name. So if it matches name *and* address or name *and* phone or name *and* middle name, then I'd be satisfied to match it. Since your query already limits to one in the best order, would the best solution be to make the `where` statement longer with `and` and `or` statements in it?

Comment: Would something like the edit above at the bottom do it?

Comment: @Ryan . . . Your edit was probably fine, but it was rejected.  I just modified the answer.  Your comment totally cleared up my confusion -- you need an additional condition.  Simple enough.